# Manipulate data table with R

Tags: r, select, subset, frame, data-manipulation

I have a data frame, for instance:

### X Y

### 1 -0.1

### 2 0

### 3 -0.2

### 4 -0.4

### 5 0

6 -0.2

I need R to select all rows between the first and 2nd zero, so that the final table is:

### 2 0

### 3 -0.2

### 4 -0.4

### 5 0

It does not work with subset. Has anyone an idea to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `which` to get the index position where `Y = 0` and subset the data.

```
inds <- which(df$Y == 0)
df <- df[inds[1]:inds[2], ]
df
#  X    Y
#2 2  0.0
#3 3 -0.2
#4 4 -0.4
#5 5  0.0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(X = 1:6, Y = c(-0.1, 0, -0.2, -0.4, 0, -0.2)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @Maik125 Sorry the function should be `which` and not `cumsum`. I corrected the answer and I also included the data which I am using to test this. It seems to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `filter` with `cumsum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(lag(cumsum(Y == 0)) < 2)
#   X    Y
#1 2  0.0
#2 3 -0.2
#3 4 -0.4
#4 5  0.0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X = 1:6, Y = c(-0.1, 0, -0.2, -0.4, 0, -0.2)), 
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```